# E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list

Tags: atom

When I try installing anything I get error E: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list:

```
deb https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor
/atom/any/ any main
```

Comment: Nope, this does not

Comment: Your error message tells you the line with the error, and file that needs correction. The aforementioned link provides your answer, you adjust for your own circumstances (ie. different source).

Comment: Malformed entry 54 means there is an error on line 54 of the file. Malformed entry 1 means there is an error on the 1st line of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Malformed entry 1 means there is an error on line 1 of the file.

Line 1 is malformed because the line is split into two lines. The contents of the file should look like this:

```
deb https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main
```

Run the following command to automatically edit and fix the file:

```
sudo sed -i 'N;s/\n//g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list
```